# How to programmatically provision temporary IoT Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

Using Javascript/Nodejs how does one programmatically get a temporary provisioning claim certificate to send to the IoT device by a trusted user/installer? I have a Provisioning Template already created in my IoT Core and I can manually add it to the device, but I need a way to do it programmatically. AWS's documentation seems incredibly vague and void of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Overview

1. Create a user with appropriate access on AWS
2. Obtain user’s `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`
3. Configure, Build, and Run Javascript AWS SDK
4. Get the Temporary Provisioning Certificate

## **Step 1**

#### Create a user with appropriate access on AWS

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/provision-wo-cert.html#trusted-user

Log into AWS as *root user* or IAM user with the ability to create IAM users.

At the **Services** menu on the top menu search “IAM”

Select the **IAM** service in the populated list

##### Create a Policy to Create/Request a Provisioning Certificate

Select in the left-hand navigation **Access Management > Policies**

Select **Create Policy**

Select **JSON** tab

Inside the `"Statement": [ ]` array paste the following code, adjusting the REGION, ACCOUNT NUMBER, and TEMPLATE NAME data:

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "iot:CreateProvisioningClaim"
      ],
      "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:iot:REGION:ACCOUNT NUMBER:provisioningtemplate/TEMPLATE NAME"
      ]
}
```

*Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/provision-wo-cert.html#trusted-user

**It should be noted that at the time of this writing the code example in the AWS docs (see URL above) is missing the service field “iot” in arn:aws:**iot**:us-east-1… (pull request submitted for changes 5/20/2022)*

Select **Next:Tags**

Add appropriate tags/descriptions

Select **Next:Review**

Name it `IoTCreateProvisioningClaim` and add a memorable description

Select **Create Policy**

##### Create a Users Group

Select in the left-hand navigation **Access Management** **> User groups**

Select **Create group**

Name the group *"IoTThingsRegistrars”* and give it the `AWSIoTThingsRegistration` and the newly created `IoTCreateProvisioningClaim` permissions by searching them in the **Attach permissions policies -** ***Optional*** section and selecting the checkbox next to them.

Click **Create group** at the bottom of the page

##### Create a User

Select in the left-hand navigation **Acess Management** **> Users**

Select **Add users**

Name the new user *“ProgrammaticIoTThingsRegistrar”*

Under **Select AWS access type** select the **Access key - Programmatic access** checkbox only

Select **Next: Permissions**

With “*Add user to group*” box selected, select the newly created **IoTThingsRegistrars** group checkbox

Select **Next: Tags**

Add any descriptive tags

Select **Next: Review**

Select **Create user**

Observe that you now have access to the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key

## Step 2

#### Obtain user’s `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`

Save in a secure location the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key (Download CSV)

## Step 3

#### Configure, Build, and Run Javascript AWS SDK

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/configuring-the-jssdk.html

##### Prerequisites:

- Install Nodejs v14+
- A Provisioning Template that’s already created in AWS IoT Core.

  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/provision-template.html
  - https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iot/home?region=us-east-1#/provisioningtemplatehub

##### Create an example Provisioning Application for this tutorial

In your preferred CLI create a directory called IoTProvisioningExample

`mkdir IoTProvisioningExample`

`cd IoTProvisioningExample`

Add the AWS SDK Client IoT to your project
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-iot/index.html#installing

`npm install @aws-sdk/client-iot`

Create a file to add the provisioning code

`nano index.js`

In `index.js` paste in the following code:

```
import { IoTClient, CreateProvisioningClaimCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-iot";

const client = new IoTClient({ region: "us-east-1" }); // your correct region
const input = { 
    templateName: 'provisioning\_template\_created\_in\_step3\_prerequisites'
}

const command = new CreateProvisioningClaimCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
console.log(response);
```

##### Add credentials to your OS or APP so the AWS SDK can find them.

Place `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` in a location where the Javascript AWS SDK can automatically find them respective to your operating system, Environment Variables File, or EC2 instance.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html

For example, if using windows:

`cd /c/Users/'User Name'/`

`mkdir .aws`

In this directory create 2 new files ***without*** extensions (like `.txt` or `.js`) simply named `config` and `credentials`

In `.aws/credentials` add and save:

```
[default] 
aws_access_key_id = <YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID> 
aws_secret_access_key = <YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
```

In `.aws/config` add and save:

```
[default] 
region = <YOUR_REGION> // us-east-1
```

## Step 4

#### Get the Temporary Provisioning Certificate

Return to your application directory and run:

`node index.js`

You should get a response like:

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: '62f6e183-ae40-\*\*\*\*-94d0-8ca25k31e4a70',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  certificateId: {
      // pems, private keys, etc
  }
}
```